# VSCode cannot find my custom modules: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm running macOS and this problem involves python code

So I have two files that are relevant inside the file 'oppia': 'core' and 'scripts'.

oppia/ ('pwd' gives -> .../oppia)

```
core/

    utils.py

scripts/

    install_install_party.py
```

Inside scripts, there is a file named 'install_third_party.py' which contains the line

```
from core import utils
```

But this gives me the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

However, this does NOT happen when I run it through the command line (while being inside oppia/)

```
python -m scripts.install_third_party
```

I made sure that I was in the correct directory before running the code on VSCode (inside oppia).

I tried 'cd oppia'  and opening VSCode inside the 'oppia' folder, but nothing worked and I keep getting the moduleNotFoundError.

Note: I am using a virtual environment using direnv and pyenv, so when I enter oppia, I am automatically activating the virtual environment. I made sure this works by using echo $VIRTUAL_ENV and getting the correct path.

As mentioned above, the script works when I run it through the command line.
I have tried copying the 'core' file inside 'scripts' (where my install_third_party.py is located) expecting that it to work as 'core' is literally in the same directory as 'install_third_party.py' now (even though 'core' shouldn't be in that directory). It did stop giving me the moduleNotFoundError for 'core', but now it's giving me a new error:

```
from scripts import install_dependencies_json_packages
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

what?...

'install_third_party.py' is INSIDE scripts, how can it not find 'scripts'?

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When you're running a script from inside a subfolder the import utility is not aware of any higher levels of packages, such as `scripts`. One way to avoid this happening is to have the main script in the root folder of the package. That way all other scripts are at lower levels relative to it and importing will work fine.

Comment: This is **not** a VSCode issue. Even though you won't have this kind of behavior in, say, PyCharm, the simple fact is that PyCharm does additional things by automatically adding project folders to PATH, while VSCode Python extension simply uses Python import utility as-is.

Comment: You can try to open your settings and search for `Execute In File Dir` and uncheck it.

Comment: @NotAName Thanks, this solves the problem, but I am contributing to open source, so I can't move any of the scripts around. Do you suggest I just use a different editor like Sublime? Or, is there a way to 'fix' my issue on VSCode

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT It was already unchecked :(
I attempted to run the code while having it both checked and unchecked and I got the same problem.

Comment: Why not simply have a `main.py` in the root folder? If you have multiple scripts to run depending on the situation you import them all in `main.py` and have a single api for you users. It's better for both imports and usability.